# should I use RDS with aurora or with mysql

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

We have a research project where we have to create a database and insert around 60 millions of records in one of the table.
We have setup a AWS account and we are using RDS with an Aurora database.
When inserting the 60 millions records, it takes forever (almost 1 day).
On my small pc with an sql server, I can do it in a few minutes.
After some search I found out that Aurora is not the one to use to do massive writes.
If we switch to mysql or another one, will we get better performances ?

We don't care about security (we can recreate the db on demand) or parallel request and duplication. All we want is to store the data, and do it fast.

thanks.

Comment: What size Aurora instance are you using? Aurora MySQL on R4.16xlarge can process 200,000 writes per second ([source](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/10/amazon-aurora-mysql-doubles-maxiumum-write-throughput-with-support-for-r4-instances/)), so, assuming your source can support the throughout, you could write 60M items in 5 minutes with that instance type.

Comment: it is RDS with an Aurora instance. Does it make sense (I'm new to this "confusing" terminology).

Comment: Yes, but you can increase the capacity of your instance (the machine your Aurora DB is running on); an Aurora DB running on a T3 doesn’t have the same computing power or capabilities as the R4.16xlarge. Increase your clusters instance size and your throughput will increase; be warned though, increased instance size = more resources = increased costs.

Comment: Yes, each step increasing the instance size approximately doubles the cost. I have benchmarked very large Aurora instances and found they can provide performance as good as physical servers. But the entry-level instance sizes probably not. Cloud resources are good for convenience, but not for performance or affordability.

Comment: Show us the Insert statement.  There are a lot of _slow_ ways to insert 60M rows; only a few _fast_ ways.  Also, what is the network latency between your code that is doing the Inserts and the Amazon server?

Comment: I'm using SSIS to do the ETL. I spend a few hours yesterday trying different things, and the speed is always the same: around 15sec to insert 10 000 rows (each rows is 2 int, 1 date, and a varchar(40), so nothing big).  I tried playing with the buffers, with the transaction, but I always get the same speed.        What is the best setup (RDS with which database (mysql, sqlserver... ) for doing massive insert?

Comment: @BenoitDesrosiers - I'll repeat the same question that others have asked: what is your instance type?

Comment: what is the exact info you need and where do I get it ? is there a command, or where do I look in the interface ?  Sorry I'm new to AWS.

Comment: does RDS with Aurora MySQL Serverless with MySQL 5.7 (default.aurora-mysql5.7). is a good answer ?